# Hosting Email for domain on other hosting

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, email, plesk

I have a website (e.g: mydomain.com) hosted on squarespace.com and I want to setup email account on another dedicated server running Parallels Plesk CPanel. I have requested access to DNS of the website domain name.

How can I have the subdomain (e.g: webmail.mydomain.com) linked to dedicated server and have the email account like myname@mydomain.com working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open the control panel of your domain name provider.
If you bought your domain with SquareSpace and you manage it through it, follow these instructions
http://help.squarespace.com/guides/opening-dns-settings

Then, modify the MX records under DNS settings according to the new web server.

About the subdomain `webmail.example.com`: it depends on your new hosting. If it has an email client you can access from that address, you need also to edit your Record A domain for that URL and point it to the IP address of your new server, and change the CNAME accordingly (but that one is not mandatory).

Here's an example of the complete procedure http://help.squarespace.com/guides/how-do-i-set-up-zoho-mail-for-my-domain

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is what I have done. Modify MX records `subdomain: mail.mydomain.com, Priority: 10, Hostname: server ip`, and add A records `subdomain: webmail.mydomain.com, ip address: server ip`. Now I am able to access webmail and send email from it. But I can't receive email send to it.  What I have done wrong?

Comment: Change your MX to what your web hosting says. Here you can see an example http://help.squarespace.com/guides/how-do-i-set-up-zoho-mail-for-my-domain